# Logging to CSV using Enterprise Library with header

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise Library to log data into a CSV file. It writes into the CSV file but it does not include headers and it writes all the parameters on a different line.Something like this:

```
Timestamp: 4/14/2011 6:41:49 PM
Message: Starting Application
Category: General
Priority: -1
EventId: 0
Severity: Information
Title:
Machine: 
App Domain: EnterpriseLib.vshost.exe
ProcessId: 10792
Process Name: 
Thread Name: 
Win32 ThreadId:7976
Extended Properties:
```

Is there a way to format the output log so as to have parameters listed in a tabular forma, with headers like Timestamp , Category so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

By headers do you mean a header at the top of the file?  Or a header for every record in the file?

The output format is controlled by the formatter template.  This is usually defined in the configuration file.  For a CSV file you would want to use a template similar to:

```
<formatters>
  <add template="&quot;{timestamp}&quot;,&quot;{severity}&quot;,&quot;{message}&quot;"
    type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    name="SimpleTextFormatter" />
</formatters>
```

This would result in the following output:

> "4/14/2011 7:34:53
>   PM","Information","This is the
>   message!"

You can use the configuration tool to insert any other tokens (e.g. {category} ) that you wish to log.

Note that if you want a proper CSV format you will have to ensure that double quotes are escaped.

Comment: I could get the CSV formatting by escaping the double quotes. By header i mean adding the header to each column. Like above the time that is diplayed i want "timestamp" written, above message i want "message" written so on..

Comment: If you want your header to be on a per record basis, then you can just set the header property of the listener.  If you want the header only at the top of the file, I don't think that is supported out of the box.  You could write your own listener to do it or write a script that adds the header after the log file has been closed.